# I lost the taskbar on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-lite

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I lost the taskbar on my Raspberry Pi
but I can't figure out how to bring it back.
What can I do?

[image: Raspberry Pi screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just do an update, this is a known problem with the latest Raspbian Stretch image. When you enable the VNC server, this can happen. Alternatively, if you don't need the VNC server, you can disable it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion... still doesn't work. All started after i did a dist-upgrade. Hopefully it works with a future update.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving/renaming/deleting `~/.config/lxpanel` then logging out and back in perhaps?

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the Raspberry PI - (3 B+) - with no programming experience, however, after I looked around the forums and tried different suggestions the following worked for me, and I was able to bring back the **taskbar** for the session I was in. (without rebooting)

Using the Terminal this command worked for me:

```
sudo startlxde-pi
```

It will restart the taskbar and will start two new Terminal windows.  Use one of this newly opened terminal windows to run the following command:

```
sudo lxpanelctl restart
```

DO NOT CLOSE THE TERMINAL WINDOW SESSIONS USED TO ENTER THE ABOVE COMMANDS - LEAVE THEM OPEN UNTIL YOU CAN REBOOT.

It appears this is only a temporary fix until you are able to reboot.  In my case, after a reboot, I got my **taskbar** back.

*- I did not want to reboot because I was downloading a large file and did not want to lose and restart the download.*

If anyone knows of a process that will restore the taskbar PERMANENTLY, without having to reboot, please reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of this works if you have a VNC connection to the raspi, no taskbar and no way to even get a terminal. so the real question would be: how do you get a terminal started while VNC into the raspberry when there is no taskbar. VNC only seems to let you send ctrl-alt-del but you need ctrl-alt-T. Mine broke up after updating to the latest raspian..

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114856)

Comment: Try using alt - F2, it is a general linux start command, something like Win+R in windows...

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal on VNC by right-clicking on a Desktop icon (if you have one) and choose option "Open Terminal here".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it might be connected to the display ports.
Im my case HDMI-Port-2 had no taskbar and with HDMI-Port-1 everything was fine.
Try, whether you can move the mouse across the borders of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for others who find it, the issue is likely the screen resolution configured for the VNC server.  I use TightVNC, and, for example, if I start it with the command:

> tightvncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24

I get exactly what you have shown (no taskbar).  However, if I start it with:

> tightvncserver -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24

The taskbar is displayed properly in the VNC viewer.

There is also a bug reported to tightvnc about this that includes a workaround:
https://sourceforge.net/p/vnc-tight/bugs/1537/
The workaround is:

> sudo apt remove lxplug-volumepulse

> sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. Realized that I had HDMI-1 unplugged and it was only using HDMI-2.  Swapped the plugs and all is well.